# TS2403 error at every typescript-react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript

> ERROR in [at-loader] ..\node_modules\@types\react\index.d.ts:3376:13 
>      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable >'a' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps, >HTMLAnchorElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLAnchorElement>'.

I used microsofts [TypeScript React Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter#typescript-react-starter) and i am using for almost a month. But as if today i couldn't. Then i try adding typescript for myself and same error again. What can i do ?

Comment: We need more details for this to be answerable. Can you show us the version of TypeScript and React that you are using, including relevant dependencies, before and after it stopped working?

Comment: See a diagnosis here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45619111/1606061

Comment: Discussion on DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/18708